# how can get rendition of Epub book at first for highlight some text

Tags: react-native, epub

I Use `Epubjs-rn` to Open Epub book
I have `rendition` from `onSelected`  method , but i want get `rendition`  when book open , and highlight some text by cfi

my code:

```
   onSelected={(cfiRange, rendition) => {
                        console.log("text is selected");
                        this.setState({ selectedCfi: cfiRange });
                        rendition.highlight(cfiRange, {}, (e) => { console.log(e) }, undefined, { 'fill': 'lightblue' });
     
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve that with get `ref` of `epub` component like this:

```
<Epub
    ref={ref => this.epub = ref}
    // other props
/>
```

then you can call that like :

```
this.epub.rendition.highlight(...)
```